# Apache Http Client Put Request Error

Tags: apache, scala, http

I'm trying to upload a file using the Apache Http Client's PUT method. The code is as below;

```
  def putFile(resource: String, file: File): (Int, String) = {
    val httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(connManager)
    httpClient.getCredentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials(un, pw))
    val url = address + "/" + resource
    val put = new HttpPut(url)
    put.setEntity(new FileEntity(file, "application/xml"))

    executeHttp(httpClient, put) match {
      case Success(answer) => (answer.getStatusLine.getStatusCode, "Successfully uploaded file")
      case Failure(e) => {
        e.printStackTrace()
        (-1, e.getMessage)
      }
    }
  }
```

When I tried running the method, I get to see the following error:

```
org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultResponseParser.java:101)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:252)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:281)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:247)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:219)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:298)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:633)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:454)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
```

I do not know what has gone wrong? I'm able to do GET requests, but PUT seems not to work! Any clues as to where I should look for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look on the server. If `GET` Works, but `PUT` does not, then you have to figure out the receiving end.

Also, you may want to write a simple HTML File that has a form with PUT Method in it to rule out your Java Part.

As a sidenode: Its technically possible that something in between stops the request from going through or the response reaching you. Best setup a dummy HTTP Server to do the testing against.

Maybe its also a timeout issue, so the server takes to long to process your PUT.

Comment: After almost a month, I'm looking at this issue. What I noticed is that I wrote another client implementation using the Apache CXF library and I'm able to send PUT requests successfully through. It seems to fail only with the Apache HttpComponents. It is terribly confusing.

Comment: Hmm... that alters the question somewhat. Please do edit this into your question. Code from CXF that works and Code from HC that does not. Also do note the versions that you use, maybe its a bug and then knowing the versions of the libraries is key to figure it out. - Debugging: Open a Packet Sniffer (e.G. Wireshark) and look at the two requests - maybe its visible there; If that doesn't work create a simple HTML Form that fires this request so you can see if the client or the server is the problem.

Comment: @sparkr What was the solution in the end? While I'm glad for the 15 points of best answer, I'd rather see a more direct fix. If its been too long ago, consider deleting the question. Keep in mind that SO is aimed at all the people who will come here, looking for help. So, if my answer actually solved the problem: great. Else, please provide the solution in your own answer or delete the question so its not misguiding. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

The connection you are trying to use is a stale connection and therefore the request is failing.

But why are you only seeing an error for the PUT request and you are not seeing it for the GET request?

If you check the DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler class you will see that by default HttpClient attempts to automatically recover from I/O exceptions. The default auto-recovery mechanism is limited to just a few exceptions that are known to be safe.

- HttpClient will make no attempt to recover from any logical or HTTP protocol errors (those derived from HttpException class).
- HttpClient will automatically retry those methods that are assumed to be idempotent. **Your GET request, but not your PUT request!!**
- HttpClient will automatically retry those methods that fail with a transport exception while the HTTP request is still being transmitted to the target server (i.e. the request has not been fully transmitted to the server).

This is why you don't notice any error with your GET request, because the retry mechanism handles it.

You should define a CustomHttpRequestRetryHandler extending the DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler. Something like this:

```
public class CustomHttpRequestRetryHandler extends DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler {

  @Override
  public boolean retryRequest(IOException exception, int executionCount, HttpContext context) {
    if(exception instanceof NoHttpResponseException) {
      return true;
    }
    return super.retryRequest(exception, executionCount, context);
  }

}
```

Then just assign your CustomHttpRequestRetryHandler

```
final HttpClientBuilder httpClientBuilder = HttpClients.custom();
httpClientBuilder.setRetryHandler(new CustomHttpRequestRetryHandler());
```

And that's it, now your PUT request is handled by your new RetryHandler (like the GET was by the default one)